# Ubuntu 17.10 Freezes Very Frequently

Tags: xorg, 17.10, freeze, wayland

This is a problem I've been having for a long time, but it recently has become unbearable. My computer will completely freeze up, recently it's been happening after only an hour or two of uptime but it used to be very rare. To be more specific, I am unable to type or move the mouse, if there's video playing it freezes and if there's audio it loops the same half second sound bite forever. Not even REISUB has any effect, I simply have to hard reset everytime. Sometimes it happens randomly, but it's most likely to happen while video is playing - especially if it's full screen. There has never been any sign it's about to freeze, one moment everything's fine and the next it's unrecoverable.

This happened even before I upgraded to Ubuntu 17 (from 16), and for awhile after upgrading it almost never froze. I have seen the advice about switching bay to Xorg from Wayland and would prefer to avoid that if there is any alternative because when running Xorg `gnome-shell` takes up ~20% of my CPU constantly as I use integrated graphics.

**System Specs:**

- OS: Ubuntu 17.10
- Memory: 16GB DDR4
- CPU: Intel i5-6500 (3.20GHz x 4)
- Graphics: integrated graphics
- GNOME: 3.26.2
- Disk: 256GB SSD

Here's an excerpt from `/var/log/syslog` of things that happened right before the crash. I don't particularly believe that `ddclient` or signal could be causing an entire system freeze as they're not vital services, but at this point I'm completely lost.

```
Mar  7 18:26:54 Olivaw signal-desktop.desktop[13134]: {"name":"log","hostname":"Olivaw","pid":13134,"level":30,"msg":"Sending a keepalive message","time":"2018-03-08T00:26:54.265Z","v":0}
Mar  7 18:27:29 Olivaw systemd-resolved[1161]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 198.18.0.1.
Mar  7 18:27:49 Olivaw signal-desktop.desktop[13134]: {"name":"log","hostname":"Olivaw","pid":13134,"level":30,"msg":"Sending a keepalive message","time":"2018-03-08T00:27:49.348Z","v":0}
Mar  7 18:28:01 Olivaw CRON[13619]: (pcp) CMD ( /usr/lib/pcp/bin/pmie_check -C)
Mar  7 18:28:44 Olivaw signal-desktop.desktop[13134]: {"name":"log","hostname":"Olivaw","pid":13134,"level":30,"msg":"Sending a keepalive message","time":"2018-03-08T00:28:44.432Z","v":0}
Mar  7 18:28:44 Olivaw ddclient[9448]: WARNING:  file /etc/ddclient.conf: Cannot open file '/etc/ddclient.conf'. (Permission denied)
Mar  7 18:28:44 Olivaw ddclient[9448]: WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache: Cannot open file '/var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache'. (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Can you switch to the console by CTRL+ALT+F2?

Comment: Can you check if you have a working swap partioton? Had the same problem and the swap partition was broken

Comment: @davidbaumann My swap partition seems to be okay, the disk utility doesn't say anything is wrong with it. [Here's a copy of /proc/meminfo](https://justpaste.it/1i17e) although everything seems to be working well right now.

Comment: @davidbaumann Pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 does nothing when it's frozen. Interestingly, I doubt this could be related, I just checked and the session I'm using right now corresponds to F2, and pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 brings me to the login page for a different session, which means logging in after booting up defaulted to the F2 one.

Comment: So try F3 when it's stuck.

Comment: Please run memtest86.

Comment: I concur with @davidbaumann. This looks like a hardware issue. See [How do I run memtest86+?](/q/591488/175814)

Comment: I have this same issue and have replaced my motherboard, cpu, and power supply. It's maddening.

Comment: I have the same problem (but on 2 different PCs). After upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04, Desktop freezes and only the mouse cursor is moving. After switching to console and back to desktop, the freeze is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a memory leak. Try to take a look at the task manager and see if a program is "leaking".